DataTable Deselect is not updating the value of the Array. I am using modernize vuetify VueJs Admin template
I am using Modernize vuetify VueJs Admin template. There I am using Selectable dataTable. The dataTable is working fine except one issue. When I am selecting a row, It's adding the items to the array. But on deselect It's not removing/updating the array.
This is the HTML Part
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="12" lg="7">
    <UiParentCard title="Select Services">
      <v-text-field v-model="search" append-inner-icon="mdi-magnify" label="Search" 
        single-line hide-details class="mb-5" />
      <v-data-table item-value="name" return-object items-per-page="5" :headers="headers"
        :items="BasicServices" v-model="selected" :search="search" show-select 
        class="border rounded-md">
      </v-data-table>
    </UiParentCard>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="12" lg="7">
    <pre>{{ selected }}</pre>
  </v-col>
</v-row>


JS Part
const selected = ref();
const search = ref();
const customsearch = ref();
const headers : any = ref([
    { title: 'Name', align: 'start', key: 'name' },
    { title: 'Cost', align: 'start', key: 'cost' },
    { title: 'Hours', align: 'start', key: 'hours' },
])

const filtrable = ref('')
function filterOnlyCapsText(value: { toString: () => string; } | null, query: string | null, item: any) {
    return value != null &&
        query != null &&
        typeof value === 'string' &&
        value.toString().toLocaleUpperCase().indexOf(query) !== -1
}

